# Can we define the imaginary power of a negative number unambiguously?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm trying to calculate the following:

$$
|a^{(\frac{1}{2}+ib)}|,
$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and $a<0$. So what I am doing is:

$$
|a^{(\frac{1}{2}+ib)}|=\left|(-|a|)^{(\frac{1}{2}+ib)}\right|=|a|^{\frac{1}{2}}(-1)^{ib}
$$

My problem now is that I think I can set $-1=e^{i\pi}$ or $-1=e^{-i\pi}$, and the results for each choice seem to be different:

- If I set $-1=e^{i\pi}$, then the result is $|a|^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-b}$.
- If I set $-1=e^{-i\pi}$, then the result is $|a|^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{b}$.

Am I doing something wrong or is this natural?

Comment: The modulus of a complex number should be real but for the question being asked I'm not sure what the modulus signs are for.

Comment: It’s just beacause $a$ is negative so I’m referring to its absolute value.

Comment: The answer you got is real but not because you found the modulus of the entire complex number. I think i know what you did. $(-|a|)^{\frac{1}{2}+ib} = |a|^{\frac{1}{2}+ib} (-1^{\frac{1}{2}+ib})$ and i meant the modulus signs around $|a^{\frac{1}{2}+ib}|$ aren't necessary.

Comment: The outer modulus signs let me do the following: $||a|^{1/2+ib}|=|a|^{1/2}$ and $|(-1)^{1/2+ib}|=(-1)^{ib}$.

Comment: You have to fix a branch of the logarithm in order to do it. Note that $a^z =\exp(z\log a)$.